# Running windows cmd using ruby rake

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run some windows command line calls in the same system
process using a Ruby Rake task. I need to find the way to do the calls
correctly and this calls can't be dependent on each other.

I know that the 'fork' function can be a solution, but it doesn't work
in Windows. I tried with other functions, like `IO.POPEN` and
`Process.spawn` and I didn't find a real solution.

I'm working with `Ruby 1.9.3` in windows XP.

```
task :CmdTest,:value do |t, args|
  value=args.value.to_s
  begin

    $cmd<<("set MYVAR=#{value}")
    $cmd<<("set MYVAR")
    $cmd<<("exit")
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e.message
  end
end

task :CmdTest3 do

  IO.popen("cmd", "r+") do |io|
    th = Thread.new(io) do |chan|
      chan.each {|line| puts line}
    end
    $cmd.each do |f|
      io.puts f
    end
    io.close_write
    th.join
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [win32utils](http://win32utils.rubyforge.org/), is that what you are after?

Comment: I will have a look at that link and see if it helps.